# embedded linux serial terminal multiplexer

Tags: linux, terminal, serial-port, embedded, gnu-screen

I have built a custom embedded system using debian 6.0.

using /etc/inittab i have made several (8) processes running on different /dev/ttyX terminals, which i can switch between using Alt+FX key combination. the thing is using this setup i need to attach a keyboard/monitor to device and reboot it, to be able to operate on it, which is so undesirable. i know linux supports terminals through serial port and i have a couple of them on the device, but i need to have all these processes output in a single serial port terminal. i have found about screen utility for terminal multiplexing, but still not sure if this is the way to go, and the actual setup that needs to be done.

any experience or best practice on this scenario would be highly appreciated

Comment: Why wouldn't screen be the way to go? I think you would just need to use the commands screen and exec in your screenrc file, to make the processes start automatically, each in a separate screen window. I have never done this though.

Comment: thanks, but does screen have a functionality like respawn in /etc/inittab ? i need that.

Comment: I don't know, but you could get the same functionality easily by wrapping a simple shell script around the binaries. I suggest you post a followup question on StackOverflow if you want a quick answer on how to do that.

Comment: or is it possible to attach a screen window to a running process or terminal?

Comment: no, you have to start it within screen.

Comment: i think the code to respawn a process is `#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ]; do
    /bin/ls -l /home/znx
done` perhaps with a signal handler to handle sigint

Comment: You probably want to put a sleep in there after the process ends, to avoid overloading the system if a process is repeatedly stillborn.

Comment: it would have been great if i could maintain the old way, while testing new way, but i cannot have multiple instances of those processes running concurrently. can screen **demultiplex** it's output into two terminals, one to /dev/tty1 and the other to /dev/ttyS0

Comment: @aliz: Sure, you can run `screen -x` and attach the same screen in two terminals.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using `screen(1)`'s `hardstatus` line; `screen(1)` can be pretty confusing without it, at least when you're trying to learn.

Some examples stolen from https://serverfault.com/questions/3740/what-are-useful-screenrc-settings

```
hardstatus lastline                                    
#hardstatus string '%{= mK}%-Lw%{= KW}%50>%n%f* %t%{= mK}%+Lw%< %{= kG}%-=%D %d %M %Y %c:%s%{-}'
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B} %d/%m %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

All those magic incantations might be a bit much to stomach; I had a nice set I used to love, but that hard drive is currently sitting on a shelf. Maybe hunt around a little bit to collect a few, and look for descriptions of them. :)

I recall needing both `hardstatus lastline` and `hardstatus string ...`, but I cannot recall the consequences of leaving off the `lastline` line.

Answer (score 1):

What about the new Unicode aware multiplexer called Tmux which can be found on sourceforge.

See http://tmux.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago there was "mscreen", originally from SCO Unix. I don't know if it's still avilable.
Today there is the "GNU Screen" project:

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/